# The meaning of "to be kind to your service" and "moco" in this acceptance speech

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was watching the acceptance speech of Emilia Clarke at Britannia Awards. I've heard several phrases that I can't understand the meanings of. I didn't find any definition for them through googling.

Here is her [speech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KB0LeVInKuE).

The first one occurs at 1:11. She says:

> **Be kind to your service** everyone. There might be thanking you in a speech someday.

What does it mean **"to be kind to your service"**?

The second one occurs at 2:45. She says:

> So Bafta I just want to thank you for giving me an excuse to thank
>   them in front of more people than, you know, the **moco** unit of Game
>   of Thrones.

What is the meaning of **"moco"** here?

Comment: **moco** is shorthand for MOtion COntrol  (just as, for example, **telecom** is a shortened form of "telecommunications"). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_control_photography The *unit* is the team of skilled technicians and artists who do this work for the show.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo That's great, thank you. So she shows her gratitude to Bafta for giving her the change of *telling them thank you  in front of more people instead of just thanking them in front the cameras of the show (game of thrones)*

Answer (score 0):

She's saying,

> Be kind to your **servers**.

And, as your other comment already says:

> moco is shorthand for [MOtion COntrol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_control_photography) (just as, for example, telecom is a shortened form of "telecommunications"). The unit is the team of skilled technicians and artists who do this work for the show. – [Tᴚoɯɐuo](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/183871/the-meaning-of-to-be-kind-to-your-service-and-moco-in-this-acceptance-speech#comment364348_183871)

Comment: I believe it's also saying, "**They** might be thanking you in a speech someday."

Comment: @J.R. Yes, I agree with you. I also think that she is saying **"they"** (It seems more grammatical to me), but automatic subtitle under the video writes "there" not "they", and "service" not "servers", so since she has a strong British accent and she is talking a little too fast, I thought maybe I was wrong and the subtitle was correct.